# IIS log analysis - how to retrieve referer information

Tags: asp.net, iis, logfiles

As per this MSDN article:

> [W3C Extended Log File Format (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/676400bc-8969-4aa7-851a-9319490a9bbb.mspx?mfr=true)

It says `cs(Referrer)` contains the REFERER information that can be read from the IIS log files.

I am trying to display the log information using an ASP.NET Repeater control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptlIISLogEntries" runat="server">
...
...
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("time")%></td>
            <td><%# Eval("cs(Referrer)")%></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The line with `Eval("cs(Referrer)"` throws an exception:

> `DataBinding:'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'cs'.`

My question is, how do I display the REFERER information in the repeater?

The code to parse the log file and bind it to the repeater is as follows:

```
string theDate =txtDate.Text;
        string FILE_NAME = @"\\" +txtMachine.Text +
           @"\C$\WINNT\System32\LogFiles\" +  
          drpSiteBox.SelectedItem.Text + @"\ex" + theDate + ".log";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILE_NAME, FileMode.Open,
                             FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs); 
        string strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        fs.Close();
        sr=null;
        fs=null;

        string[] arLogLines = strResult.Split(Convert.ToChar("\n"));
        dt = new DataTable("log");
        string revisedColmNames=arLogLines[3].Replace("#Fields: ","");
        string[] arColm=revisedColmNames.Split(Convert.ToChar(" "));
for(int j=0;j<arColm.Length;j++)
{   
    dt.Columns.Add(arColm[j]);
    Debug.WriteLine(arColm[j]);
}
for (i =arLogLines.Length-1; i>3;i--)
{  
    // need this because some logs get additional data appended 
    // aren't unhandled exceptions great? The CLR just loves 'em...
    try
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(arLogLines[i].Split(Convert.ToChar(" ")));
    }
    catch {}

}
DataGrid1.DataSource=dt;
DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Note: this is the same code as in http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20021203.asp

Comment: Are you logging this information? How are you logging it, and how are you retrieving it?

Comment: I log the requests by checking the Enable logging checkbox in inetmgr console
the extended properties checkbox is also checked

For retrieving I am using Filestream to parse the log file and then display using asp.net repeater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is to do with the way that the data binder operates over the data table and handles column/property names. `Eval` uses reflection and the parentheses characters in the column names are causing this to fail (I need to jog my memory about how all this works again, it's been a while).

Just cast the underlying `Container.DataItem` to the type that it is (a `DataRowView`), then pick out the column:

```
<%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["cs(Referer)"]%>
```

This is also faster because reflection isn't used which is slow.

Also I notice that you'd spelled 'Referer' incorrectly (you have two 'r's), so watch out for that as well.

To get this to work using `Eval()` instead you need to do a bit more work. Change this:

```
for(int j=0;j<arColm.Length;j++)
{   
    dt.Columns.Add(arColm[j]);
    Debug.WriteLine(arColm[j]);
}
```

To this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < arColm.Length; j++)
{
    string colName = arColm[j].Replace("(", "_").Replace(")", "");
    dt.Columns.Add(colName);
    Debug.WriteLine(colName);
}
```

In the data binder `Eval` expression change any column with parentheses in the name from:

```
Eval("cs(Referer)")
```

to:

```
Eval("cs_Referer")
```

But I'd go with the first method, it's less intrusive and much faster.

Comment: Yes, tried it out
It worked in local environment (where i have rights to install logparser)
but didnot work in deployment server where I donot have rights to install Logparser.

Comment: @balalakshmi - ah ok, in that case you need to show us your script that opens an reads the logfiles and how you're binding this data to the Repeater control.

Comment: @Kev I tried the solution
<%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["cs(Referer)"]%> 
it works fine
Thanks for persisting on this thread to help solve my problems

Comment: Actually, he spelled it correctly: Referrer[1].  Referer is not a word in the english language, but that's how it's (mis)spelled in the HTTP specifications[2].  According to the MSDN documentation, he wants the correct spelling here, as in "cs(Referrer)"[3].  Nothing like a little spelling mistake in the spec to mess us up for the next 20 years... :-)


  [1]: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/referrer
  [2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer
  [3]: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/676400bc-8969-4aa7-851a-9319490a9bbb.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @JoshuaBeall - in the context of the answer and pertaining to HTTP it is spelled incorrectly. I too have read the spec and know fine well that `REFERER` is a typo that will continue to haunt us until the end of time :)